# Why can't const be used infront of object argument?

Tags: c++, oop

In the following code why is it if I pust `const` infront of `Data` I get the error `error C2662: 'double Data::getValue(const int,const int)' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const Data' to 'Data &'`

```
bool Data::equal(Data &aabb)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ROWS; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < MAX_COLUMNS; j++){
            if (aabb.getValue(i, j) != m[i][j])
                return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You've defined the `getvalue` method in such a way that it requires the object to be mutable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like there is no `Data::getValue(int, int) const` function. You should either change your existing `getValue` function to be `const` (note, the `const` has to come *after* the closing bracket), or add a `const` overload.

Comment: What does `const` do if it comes after the argument brackets e.g. `getValue(int, int) const`?

Comment: It means that that function can be called via a `const` reference. In specific, it makes `this` a const pointer within the context of that function.

Comment: What is a const reference? btw I got my code working thanks, just trying to understand

Comment: `Data&` => non-const reference. `const Data&` => const reference.